# How to get scrapy to use python 3 when both python versions are installed?

Tags: python, scrapy

Quick question regarding the version of python that's being used by scrapy. I installed scrapy from the `AUR` repository on archlinux and it defaults on using `python 2.7`. Scrapy has support for`python 3.3+`. Does anyone know how to force it to use 3.3 without uninstalling 2.7, can't find anything on it on the internet.

Comment: every python version has own folder for modules and own program to install modules. Pythono 3.3 should have `pip3` and `pip3.3` to install - `pip3 install scrapy` - or you can do `python3 -m pip install scrapy`

Answer (score 6):

Use [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io). You can install it with `pip`.

What I would normally do is go to the project folder, and create a virtual environment (`envname`) with the following command:

```
virtualenv -p python3 envname
```

Enable it `source envname/bin/activate` and install everything you want. Now you have a Python3 environment (I think you need to install Scrapy again for the current environment).

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall scrapy from python 2 and install it on python 3

```
pip uninstall scrapy
pip3 install scrapy
```

Check if it's working using `scrapy version -v` which will show something like this:

```
Scrapy       : 1.7.3
lxml         : 4.4.1.0
libxml2      : 2.9.9
cssselect    : 1.1.0
parsel       : 1.5.2
w3lib        : 1.21.0
Twisted      : 19.7.0
Python       : 3.7.4 (default, Sep 13 2019, 03:37:47) - [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
pyOpenSSL    : 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019)
cryptography : 2.7
Platform     : Linux-3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-centos-7.6.1810-Core
```

It says `Python : 3.7.4` which means it is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Let's follow me step by step:
Step 1: uninstall package was installed:

```
pip uninstall scrapy
```

Step 2: use pip with version of python to install scrapy such as: My python version is **3.7**, I'll use **pip3.7** .

```
pip3.7 install scrapy
```

Step 3: check version:  scrapy version -v

```
Scrapy       : 2.3.0
lxml         : 4.5.2.0
libxml2      : 2.9.10
cssselect    : 1.1.0
parsel       : 1.6.0
w3lib        : 1.22.0
Twisted      : 20.3.0
Python       : 3.7.9 (default, Aug 27 2020, 21:59:41) - [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-9)]
pyOpenSSL    : 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020)
cryptography : 3.1
Platform     : Linux-4.19.76-linuxkit-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5
```